# Plugin Page do Facebook dando "Failed to load resource"

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

Gostaria de usar o plugin "page" do Facebook, mas não estou conseguindo. Após adicionar esse codigo no começo da tag body

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

e esse no fim tag "body"

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/l2akhilleus/timeline/" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true">
<div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/l2akhilleus/timeline/"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/l2akhilleus/timeline/">L2Akhilleus</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

Atualizo a página e não carrega nem mostra nada. Fui em inspecionar elemento da pagina e ele me retornou isso e não sei como prosseguir:

> file://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5 Failed to load 
>   resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Ja fui nesse link e copiei todo o codigo e salvei em um arquivo, chamei o codigo `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sdk.js"></script>` e ainda não mostra o plugin na minha página...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente o problema é está sendo assumido que o recurso está no computador, talvez por você estar deixando a URL sem protocolo. Se olhar a mensagem de erro, o recurso buscado está iniciando com `file://`.

Tente utilizar:

```js
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
```

Comment: Perfeito! coloquei online e funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

O meu só funcionou da seguinte maneira

código antigo

```
//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=
```

código ajustado

```
//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.10&amp;appId=
```

Eu adiocionei um "**amp;**" depois dos "**&**"